# Database schema for job offers with some common attributes

Tags: database-design, schema

I'm trying to design a database in order to store IT job offers. My data comes from 4 different websites and unfortunately only part of their attributes (column names) are common. It looks like this:

```
Website 1: title, overall experience level
Webiste 2: title, overall experience level, skills required, skills nice to see
Website 3: title, overall experience level, skills required, level of required skills (junior or mid or senior)
Webiste 4: title, overall experience level, skills required, level of required skills (in years), skills nice to see, language, level of langauge
```

I would like to know how would you design a database with this kind of data? I did some research and found that it can be done in different ways:

Approach 1: only one table with all attributes (there will be a lot of nulls) but to be honest I think it's bad idea.

Approach 2: one table storing common attributes to all websites and rest of attributes in separate tables. Also I must notice that each job offer has multiple values in `skills required` and `skills nice to see attributes` so I think these two must be in many-to-many relationship with `JobOffer table`
[image]

Approach 3: Four tables with attributes assigned to each of websites (so each table represents each website with its atrributes). And like in previous approach `skills required` and `skills nice to see` are in many-to-many relationship with almost (except `WEBSITE1` table) every website table
[image]

Approach 4: Your own approach because none of these above fit well to this problem. (I've never been designing database before so I'm aware that all 3 approaches proposed by me could be wrong)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sparse table (one table with NULLs in unused columns) seems to be the simplest solution. And it provides simple solid unified processing.

Comment: Look into the following approach:  Class Table Inheritance.  It resembles your approach 2, but with more to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering "nice to see skills" and "required skills" as wholly separate attributes is a mistake. They are all just skills. Each `Job` has `Skills` then those `JobSkills` are either `Required` or not (yes/no). In particular, a skill might be required for one job and optional for another. Further, I'd suggest that a language is just another skill.

Mostly, it would seem like this would fit into a schema that looks something like this, where several of the things you have in separate tables become attributes on the Job-Skill cross reference.

- Skill

  - SkillId
  - Name
  - Type (technical, language, etc)
- Job

  - JobId
  - Name
  - Description
  - Overall level
  - Source website
- JobSkill

  - JobId
  - SkillId
  - IsRequired
  - SkillLevel